# Why is vertex drawing ignoring grid snap settings?

Tags: vertices, snapping

If I want to draw some vertices on the ground plane, I seem to have to place the first vertex with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> (not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> as the manual states), then Extrude the rest of the vertices using <kbd>E</kbd>, which is fine, except that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> seems to ignore my snap to grid settings (using <kbd>E</kbd> behaves properly), so I can't accurately place that first vertex.

Is there a way of making that snap when it's placed, rather than having to move it afterwards using Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to draw some vertices on the ground plane, I seem to have to
>   place the first vertex with Ctrl-RMB (not Ctrl-LMB as the manual
>   states...

That's probably because Blender used RMB for selection by default prior to 2.8. WWas it on the 2.8 manual or the 2.79?

For your issue you have to extrude, cancel the moving of the extrude by using right clic mouse button, then move it with G (dont deselect anything by error) to get the snapping effect.